# Changing a jscript variable each time a php include is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a page that displays a product list from a database on my home page. When the user clicks on any of the products, a modal is opened and this modal contains product info, as well as a image gallery.

```
    $product_handler = new Product ($cao);
    $products = $product_handler->getProducts();
    if($products) {
        /* @var $prod Product */
        foreach ($products as $key => $prod) {


            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <img class="image-modal"  data-toggle="modal" style="width: 192px; height:192px;"  data-target="#<?php echo $prod->prod_name;?>Modal" src="<?php echo $prod->prod_icon; ?>">
            <a data-toggle="modal"  data-id="<?php echo $prod->prod_name ?>"  data-target="#<?php echo $prod->prod_name;?>Modal" class="image_modal"><h2 style='color:#2468A6'><b><?php echo $prod->prod_name ?></b></h2></a>
</div>  
    <!--------Modal starts here-------->
    <?php
$pres_path= "dub/place/folder/Presentation.php";


include $pres_path;
?>  
     <?php   
        }
    }
```

Then within the `Presentation.php` file the modal is called and this contains all the product info and the image gallery.The page also contains a big chunk of javascript used to navigate the images in the gallery.

In this javascript section I have a variable that is used to determine what the current image is.

```
    <script> 

    var currentImage = 1;
                            $('a.galleryBullet' + currentImage).addClass("active");
                            $('a.thumbnailsimage' + currentImage).addClass("active");
                            $('div.description' + currentImage).addClass("visible");

//Previous Arrow

                        $('a.previousSlideArrow').click(function () {
                            $('img.previewImage' + currentImage).hide();
                            $('a.galleryBullet' + currentImage).removeClass("active");
                            $('a.thumbnailsimage' + currentImage).removeClass("active");
                            $('div.description' + currentImage).removeClass("visible");

                            currentImage--;
                            if (currentImage == 0) {
                                currentImage = imagesTotal;
                            }
                            $('img.previewImage' + currentImage).show();
                            $('a.galleryBullet' + currentImage).addClass("active");
                            $('a.thumbnailsimage' + currentImage).addClass("active");
                            $('div.description' + currentImage).addClass("visible");

                            return false;
                        });




</script>
```

The problem I have is that when I click on one product and navigate the gallery,and then close the modal and select another product. It continues on the same number as the one I ended on in the previous modal.

**In example**. In modal 1 there is 5 slides and I **close** the modal on slide no. 3.If I then open modal 2 which contains 7 slides. I will **start** on slide no. 3

The reason for this I think, is because the variable `currentImage` is used by all of the modals. And thus, problems arise

**My question is**,

How can I make sure that each time a product is clicked, that the variable `currentImage` is set to 1

Answer (score 1):

Create an own scope for each of your "modals":

```
(function(){
 var currentImage=1;
 alert(currentImage);//1
 //...
 })();
 alert(currentImage);//undefined
```

So a "scope model" for all of your modals would look like:

```
 window.unknownfunction1.currentImage;
 window.unknownfunction2.currentImage;
```

Before it was:

```
window.currentImage;
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Is there any additional info I can provide for you to explain using a example?

Comment: @Albertus Brand Venter (by the way, where are you from?) : i think your problem is that the loaded javascripts all use the same variable and override each other, or am i wrong?

Comment: You are correct. The variable is used in the php file that contains the modal. And each product uses the same php file. So I think they are all using the same global variable. From SA, why?

Comment: @Albertus Brand Venter: my answer creates a new scope. So the variable is not part of the global window object, every js has its own scope and theres no chaos ( its easier to explain in a native language, and your name sounded quite "german")

Comment: Can I perhaps show you my code. It might make it much easier to understand. http://pastebin.com/qanD9QzU

Comment: @Albertus Brand Ventner: im not able to really understand your code, can you post the output (without the php stuff) so that im able to get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122296/discussion-between-albertus-brand-venter-and-jonas-w).